# Sinatra - Locals not displaying in erb

Tags: json, ruby, sinatra, locals

I have JSON that I want to display in a  tag on my submitted.erb but I can't get it to display.  When I PUT the JSON, I see the entirety of the parsed JSON in the console.

Here's the flow:

1. User submits a form from myform.erb
2. In my post, the following is done with the JSON:

`put '/' do
    require json
    ...
    @resp = JSON.pretty_generate(JSON.parse(json))
    redirect "/submitted/"
end`

get '/submitted/?' do
    erb :submitted, :locals => {:results => @resp}
end

Then in my submitted.erb I have <%= results %> in my pre tags.

Comment: Why do you need to pass locals unless are you rendering a partial in your erb?  Can you post the erb code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to output the string version of your object in erb you can do

```
<%= results.inspect %>
```

But you probably just need it as a string so try change

```
@resp = JSON.pretty_generate(JSON.parse(json))
```

to

```
@resp = JSON.parse(json).to_s
```